# Passing a flag from a gulp series?

Tags: gulp

I can run a task with a flag via:

```
gulp build --production
```

Is there anyway to have a task set up like this:

```
gulp.task('deploy',
gulp.series('build'));
```

And also include the flag:

```
gulp.task('deploy',
gulp.series('build --production'));
```

So I could just call `gulp deploy` to run a production build?

Comment: No, that's not possible. The closest thing would be to set up a factory function that returns parameterized task functions.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not really possible using the built-in gulp functionality, I wrote a package that makes this as easy and convenient as possible: [`gulp-parameterized`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-parameterized).

(Note: this is still a work in progress. For one thing it needs a comprehensive test suite. It's also severely lacking in documentation. However the core functionality has been tested and should work.)

Here's your example using `gulp-parameterized`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var parameterized = require('gulp-parameterized');

gulp.task('build', parameterized(function(_) {
  if (_.params.production) {
    /* production build */
  } else {
    /* development build */
  }
}));

gulp.task('deploy', parameterized.series('build --production'));
```

This also automatically parses command line flags, so you don't need to parse those yourself with `yargs` anymore.

The following commands create production builds:

```
$ gulp build --production
$ gulp deploy
```

While the following commands create development builds:

```
$ gulp build
$ gulp build --no-production
```